# Changing Textview to Imageview in ontouch drag example

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm starting out in android development, and I've been tackling the basics of a user interface, currently that means dragging and dropping images. I finally found a good example of that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9398057/android-move-a-view-on-touch-move-action-move) for a textview, but I'd like to use it to drag around an imageview. What changes would I be required to make in order to have that occur? Thanks in advance for being patient with such a basic question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These two lines:

```
_view = new TextView(this);
_view.setText("TextView!!!!!!!!");
```

Just have to be changed to:

```
_view = new ImageView(this);
_view.setImageResource(R.drawable...); // Whatever image
```

And `TextView _view;` has to be changed to `ImageView _view;`.

A note, though... you should probably learn a bit about what the code does, and how to manipulate `View` objects in Android Java before getting too heavily into code like this.

Comment: Much appreciated, and I'll do that. If you have the time, I'd love your input on what resources I should look into to help me understand it better beyond random googling of lines.

Comment: [This blog](http://android-er.blogspot.ca/2011/06/add-view-using-java-code.html) has a decent rundown of `View`s through Java. A search for ["android adding views with java"](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=android+adding+views+with+java) yields some pretty good results.

Comment: Thanks a lot, one last question, is this method less than ideal for dragging multiple views on the one activity, or can it be done?

Comment: @user1398478 It shouldn't matter how you create the objects (via Java or XML), as long as you handle them properly.