# Can i make screen as four parts & slide every part to Horizontally

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-viewpager

here is the example screen i'm looking for, Is that possible with View-Pager.
When i slide to that particular direction need to move another activity.

[image]

Comment: if you need to start new activity use image button why complicate things with view pager

Comment: Can i get the example codes in similar manner @Subash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see why you want to use ViewPager here.

You can have a parent `FrameLayout` with four `View`s, for example `ImageView`s. Then, you can:

1. Override the onTouchEvent() in the parent `FrameLayout` and detect which image was touched and act accordingly (to get an effect you may want to move your image together with the `MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE` touch event until a certain threshold and then start a new `Activity`) - You can use this post: [move a view on touch move](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9398057/android-move-a-view-on-touch-move-action-move) as an example.
2. Do the same by using [Gesture Detector](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.OnGestureListener.html).