# How to move a TextView to anywhere on the screen?

Tags: android, textview

I have a relative layout in which i have a TextView having some text "Hi ! This is john". I want to move the text to any position i want on the screen, on touching the text.I am using onTouchListener() on the Text View.Can anybody please help me.

Comment: set animation on textView

Answer (score 0):

Follow that carefully, very how set animation? 
[Android Working with XML Animations](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/06/android-working-with-xml-animations/) then visit that [android: move a view on touch move (ACTION_MOVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9398057/android-move-a-view-on-touch-move-action-move)

Comment: Thanks.It Works fine.But text having more words is not displaying.how to display text having more number of words.

Comment: set textview property android:ellipsize="marquee"

Answer (score 0):

Set `onTouch` listner on your `TextView` and according to the position of it Move it to another location you want on `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP` event..

```
private final static int START_DRAGGING = 0;
    private final static int STOP_DRAGGING = 1;   
    private int status;
    int flag=0;
    float xAxis = 0f;
    float yAxis = 0f;
    float lastXAxis = 0f;
    float lastYAxis = 0f;
...     
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent me){
          if(me.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
          status = START_DRAGGING;
          final float x = me.getX();
          final float y = me.getY();
          lastXAxis = x;
          lastYAxis = y;
          v.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
          }else if(me.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
          status = STOP_DRAGGING;
          flag=0;
          v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
          }else if(me.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE){
          if (status == START_DRAGGING){
          flag=1;
          v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
          final float x = me.getX();
          final float y = me.getY();
          final float dx = x - lastXAxis;
          final float dy = y - lastYAxis;
          xAxis += dx;
          yAxis += dy;
          v.setX((int)xAxis);
          v.setY((int)yAxis);
          v.invalidate();
          }
        }
        return false;
      }
```

Comment: Please tell me how to move the text

Comment: Can you please provide me total code for OnTouchListener()

Comment: does it work for you??

Comment: I am doing my app on API level 8 or above.But setX() in your code is of API level 11 or above.So I am unable to execute it.

Comment: try getRawX() and getRawY() insted of setX() and setY() will help you for sure,,,and let me know does it work or not??

Comment: It is saying that we should not use getRawX() and getRawY() for the view v.