# Checkbox buttons aren't responding properly when using a Scrollview to scroll through a large Imageview

Tags: android, xml, layout, checkbox, scrollview

I am making an app that requires a large png image to be able to scroll with Checkbox buttons laid on top of the image that will scroll with it. I got help from this link [Scrollview with many buttons over an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31330633/scrollview-with-many-buttons-over-an-image). Here is what I have so far.

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/svVertical"
    android:layout_below="@+id/buildingNameText"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="60dp" >

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/hsvHorizontal" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:isScrollContainer="true">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/map_view"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/dummy_floor_extra_large"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

            <CheckBox
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:id="@+id/checkBox"
                android:button="@null"
                android:background="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"
                android:layout_marginStart="21dp"
                android:backgroundTint="#22e300"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp" />

            <CheckBox
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/checkBox2"
                android:layout_below="@+id/checkBox"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/checkBox"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:buttonTint="#22e300" />

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/radioButton"
                android:layout_below="@+id/checkBox2"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/checkBox2"
                android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
                android:buttonTint="#22e300" />

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="New RadioButton"
                android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
                android:layout_below="@+id/radioButton"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/checkBox"
                android:layout_marginStart="150dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="58dp" />

            <CheckBox
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="New CheckBox"
                android:id="@+id/checkBox3"
                android:layout_below="@+id/radioButton2"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/radioButton2"
                android:layout_marginTop="32dp" />

            <Switch
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="New Switch"
                android:id="@+id/switch1"
                android:layout_below="@+id/checkBox3"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/checkBox3"
                android:layout_marginTop="42dp" />

            <Switch
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/switch2"
                android:layout_below="@+id/radioButton"
                android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/radioButton" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:id="@+id/button"
                android:layout_above="@+id/checkBox3"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/radioButton2" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
</ScrollView>
```

And here's the activity:

```
private ScrollView scrollY;
private HorizontalScrollView scrollYChild;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_floor_view);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        Window window = getWindow();
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
        window.setStatusBarColor(Color.parseColor("#505050"));
    }

    scrollY = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.svVertical);
    scrollYChild = (HorizontalScrollView) findViewById(R.id.hsvHorizontal);
}


@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    scrollYChild.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
    scrollY.onTouchEvent(event);
    return true;
}
```

The problem is the checkboxes aren't clicking properly. As a matter of fact, all the buttons aren't working. I put all those buttons in the xml file for test purposes to see which one works and the only one that works is the switches. All the rest don't work properly but I would really prefer checkboxes rather than switches in my app. Any help is appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem! If I use this code in my activity, the button pressing issue is solved but at the expense of the diagonal scrolling to be a bit tougher for the user to do.

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    scrollYChild.onTouchEvent(event);
    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    scrollYChild.onTouchEvent(event);
    scrollY.onTouchEvent(event);
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```