# Android move view to a touched position

Tags: android, move, touch-event

I'm trying to develop an android application similar to "on color measurement" or "color grab" which are already on google play.
I have problem with getting the exact position of a view (which acts like focus square) and move it to the position where the user touches the screen. I have done a lot of searches but all of them ended in onTouchEvent() which I used it but it does not work properly or maybe I have done something wrong. 
Actually the view moves but it won't be placed exactly where the user touch, it will go below the touched area in y axis with a distance.

here is my code where the mFocusRectangle is the custom view which I want to move to the touched position:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    int action = event.getAction();
if (event.getPointerCount() > 1) {
        // handle multi-touch events

    } else {
        // handle single touch events
        if(action==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){

        }
        if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            int pointerId = event.getPointerId(0);
            int pointerIndex = event.findPointerIndex(pointerId);
            // Get the pointer's current position
            float x = event.getX(pointerIndex);
            float y = event.getY(pointerIndex);
            mFocusRectangle.showStart();
            mFocusRectangle.setX(x);
            mFocusRectangle.setY(y);

        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

I have also tried MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN but the result is the same.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is your showStart() doing?

Comment: try this `float x = event.getX(0); float y = event.getY(0);` does that work?

Comment: @AwaisKing showStart() set a drawable to the mfocusRectangle. I've tried 'float x = event.getX(0); float y = event.getY(0);' but in this case also the view moves to a wrong position

Comment: @Dev showStart() set a drawable to the mfocusRectangle.

Comment: @elahe I am actually trying to find out are you using canvas and if yes where is it?

Comment: becoz when we deal with canvas we can redraw the image rather than moving it( technically both are same though)

Comment: @Dev no I did not use canvas. So what am I supposed to do now?

Comment: Here is an example http://thegeekyland.blogspot.com/2015/12/android-animations-explained.html

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
float x = event.getX(pointerIndex) - (mFocusRectangle.getWidth() / 2);
float y = event.getY(pointerIndex) - (mFocusRectangle.getHeight() / 2);
```

credits: 
Manitoba - [Android move view on touch event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23120807/android-move-view-on-touch-event/23185635#23185635)