# Making an ImageView object in android move randomly on the screen

Tags: android

Fairly new at android dev, haven't got any code for this particular step yet so ill try give as much detail as possible. I'm trying to make an ImageView object move around the android view/activity, unlike java im not able to use the random generator to translate it onto an x and or y position on the frame, if anyone could point me on the right direction or more importantly have a good idea on how to do this, that'd be great.

Comment: please read rules on how to post a question

Comment: Alright ill take a look

Answer (score 0):

There is a class in android called Random. And there is a function called nextInt() which can give you a random number. You can also calculate the width and height of your screen using [DisplayMetrices](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html) so that you can keep the image inside the device's screen. And you can also move the ImageView. See this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9398057/android-move-a-view-on-touch-move-action-move).

Comment: op is asking something different i believe ,cuz he wants to display that image at some random position ! but he clearly needs to take care of the position with respect to the screen ..may be you want to modify your answer ?

Comment: @VamsiPavanMahesh Now? :)

Comment: good .. but don't you want to give him an example of how would you do that ..like by putting layout_lefto and all so that image will be there on the screen .. ? .Anyways you can leave that to OP :)

Comment: @VamsiPavanMahesh I posted a link for moving the image. I can't write whole code for him :)

Comment: i think i have edited the question in a way that i understood ..hope that it will be accepted ..so you can write an answer for it .. or i will write by myself

Comment: @VamsiPavanMahesh If you have an answer, you can provide it freely :)

Comment: im not sure what he's asking .. otherwise i would have :D

Comment: @VamsiPavanMahesh :D But you may be right about what he is asking, so you can post your answer :)

Comment: screw it .. he did not accepted my edit suggestion and is asking the same question again and again .. waste of time