# Move a system overlay element

Tags: java, android

I have created the system overlay from the example [here](http://www.jawsware.mobi/code_OverlayView/).

In the `SampleOverlayView.java` there is a method for move event like this:

```
@Override
protected void onTouchEvent_Move(MotionEvent event) {
    info.setText("MOVE\nPOINTERS: " + event.getPointerCount());
}
```

I wish I could use this to move my overlay. I found the solution for moving my overlay (when I move the view, it does follow my finger movement). The solution is over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9398057/android-move-a-view-on-touch-move-action-move)

This solution uses, `onTouch` method, which gives the `View` and `MotionEvent` params. But in my case I dont have `view` object. View can be anything ( as its an overlay).Have only `event` param.

Any idea of how I can move overlay within my screen?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you have a `View` you are already in it. I copied the relevant parts of the guide you are linking to:

```
public class SampleOverlayView extends OverlayView {

    private TextView info;

    private float x;
    private float y;

    public SampleOverlayView(OverlayService service) {
        super(service, R.layout.overlay, 1);
    }

    public int getGravity() {
        return Gravity.TOP + Gravity.RIGHT;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onInflateView() {
        info = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.textview_info);
    }

    @Override
    protected void refreshViews() {
        info.setText("WAITING\nWAITING");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onTouchEvent_Up(MotionEvent event) {w
        info.setText("UP\nPOINTERS: " + event.getPointerCount());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onTouchEvent_Move(MotionEvent event) {
        float newX = event.getX();
        float newY = event.getY();

        float deltaX = newX - this.x;
        float deltaY = newY - this.y;

        // Move this View

        this.x = newX;
        this.y = newY;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onTouchEvent_Press(MotionEvent event) {
        this.x = event.getX();
        this.y = event.getY();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent_LongPress() {
        info.setText("LONG\nPRESS");
        return true;
    }
}
```

So you don't need a separate `View` object because that class **IS** the `View`. Just replace any occurrence of `view` in the other answer with `this`.