# swipe menu for expandable listview

Tags: android, listview, menu, expandablelistview, swipe-gesture

I want to create swipe menu for expandable listview. Something like [this](https://github.com/tycallen/SwipeMenu-Expandable-ListView). I'm using Android studio and not sure about how to add this as dependencies in Gradle. 
Or should I go with the other libraries. I'm very new to the Android so any suggestion would be helpful.

Can we also achieve that, without using any library?

Thanks!

Comment: you can import the project as a module in Android Studio

Comment: @AnirudhaAgashe: I tried importing as module, but it's displaying error at run-time.. "Error inflating class com.baoyz.swipemenulistview.SwipeMenuExpandableListView"

Comment: I was able to import the "library" folder within the given repositories as a module without any problem

Comment: @AnirudhaAgashe: Yes. So do I. But when using that library, it's displaying error in xml file "Error inflating class com.baoyz.swipemenulistview.SwipeMenuExpandableListView"

Comment: Make sure that the newly imported module is added as dependency in your project like 
compile project(path: ':swipeMenuListView')

Comment: @AnirudhaAgashe: Okay. Can you please share a working sample of it..if possible

Comment: As I said I was able to import the project and run the sample without any problem. Can you tell me what is the error that you are getting ?

Comment: @DipenDedania I had the same error. There is error in documentation, you shoud put in layout
com.allen.expandablelistview.SwipeMenuExpandableListView
instead of
com.baoyz.swipemenulistview.SwipeMenuExpandableListView