# how to swipe an image in a view in basic four directions i.e. right, left, up, down

Tags: android, android-studio, ontouchlistener, gesturedetector

I want to develop my own Accept and Decline buttons by swiping an image to right and left respectively and by swipe up and down want to open templates.I m new to android so i have no idea how to do this.

Is there any way to make this? Any hint?

I hope to be clear.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30908068/android-listview-swipe-right-and-left-to-accept-and-reject

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an `OnTouchListener`, and compute directions.

Based  on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12938787/775894):

```
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;

public class OnSwipeTouchListener implements OnTouchListener {

    private final GestureDetector gestureDetector;

    public OnSwipeTouchListener (Context ctx){
        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(ctx, new GestureListener());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    private final class GestureListener extends SimpleOnGestureListener {

        private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD = 100;
        private static final int SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD = 100;

        @Override
        public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
            boolean result = false;
            try {
                float diffY = e2.getY() - e1.getY();
                float diffX = e2.getX() - e1.getX();

                // Move the ImageView here, from diffX pixels horizontally and diffY pixels vertically

                if (Math.abs(diffX) > Math.abs(diffY)) {
                    if (Math.abs(diffX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                        if (diffX > 0) {
                            onSwipeRight();
                        } else {
                            onSwipeLeft();
                        }
                    }
                    result = true;
                } 
                else if (Math.abs(diffY) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityY) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                        if (diffY > 0) {
                            onSwipeBottom();
                        } else {
                            onSwipeTop();
                        }
                    }
                    result = true;

            } catch (Exception exception) {
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }
            return result;
        }
    }

    public void onSwipeRight() {
    }

    public void onSwipeLeft() {
    }

    public void onSwipeTop() {
    }

    public void onSwipeBottom() {
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your  help, with this i m able to get gestures but can't move my image from it's place. I want to move as gesture moves

Comment: @HarmeetKaur I edited the code, and added a comment on where you should move the image.

Comment: can you help me how can i move image. i am unable to do so

Comment: @HarmeetKaur You can either change your ImageView's margins, or use drag & drop as documented here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html

Comment: i have tried by drag and drop method but i am not able to implement it properly can u provide the code