# Sliding listview button

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, listview, android-recyclerview

I created a list view, now I want to make it just like when I **swipe** them left or right it behave like call and message button respectively.

[image].

Just like this Image. A list view carrying some data. While we **swipe** it left or right it respond. Here I need to know how can I do that make that respond as a call and message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, this action is not called a slide, this is SWIPE.
I think you can use this tutorial:
http://www.tutecentral.com/android-swipe-listview/
Also check out the answer to a similar question here:
[Android ListView Swipe Right and Left to Accept and Reject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30908068/android-listview-swipe-right-and-left-to-accept-and-reject)

Comment: Thanks a lot . It is really helpful  @SAM_U_RAI

Comment: @Innat please tick this answer as right solution for your question

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
https://github.com/nemanja-kovacevic/recycler-view-swipe-to-delete
```

for swipe to delete ..with default recycler view too..