# Android Custom View move back to original position when refreshing

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio, android-custom-view

I'm implementing a time picker which looks like this:

[image: unfinished time picker]

That yellow block is `MyCustomView`. When moving `MyCustomView`, I should calculate new date and set `tvDate`.

partial layout file:

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/tv_date">

    <RelativeLayout 
        android:id="@+id/rl">

        <MyCustomView
         android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

        <OtherViews/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

code:

```
class MyCustomView extends View{

    // move listener
    public interface IMoveCallback{
        void update(int index);
    }

    private IMoveCallback listener = null; 

    // set listener
    public void setMoveCallback(IMoveCallback callback){
        this.listener = callback;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas c){
        super.onDraw(c);
        // draw yellow block and four arrows here.
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        processDrag(v, event);
        invalidate();
        return false;
    }

    private void processDrag(View v, MotionEvent event){
        // calculate new position(left, top, right, bottom)
        v.layout(newLeft, newTop, newRight, newBottom); 
        if(listener != null){
            // calculate index by new position
            listener.update(index);
        }
    }
}

class MainActivity extends Activity implements MyCustomView.IMoveCallback{

    MyCustomView view; // view.setMoveCallback(MainActivity.this)

    @Override
    public void update(int index){
        tvDate.setText(String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()))//update tvDate
    }
}
```

If `tvDate.setText()` is removed, `MyCustomView` follows the finger, like this:

[image]

If I update `tvDate`, `MyCustomView` moves back to the center of `rl`:

[image]

I don't think it an activity-lifecycle issue. Someone mentioned `((MarginLayoutParams)rl.getLayoutParams()).topMargin` but did not explain why.
Anybody can help me?

Comment: You should be more specific. What do you mean by "its original position " ?

Comment: Also show the complete code for the activity. It may an activity-lifecycle issue

Comment: @FarhadFaghihi I have edit my question. `MainActivity` contains `onCreate` and callback. I don't think it an activity-lifecycle issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to save the location of your view and render it at the same spot when the activity resumes(coming back from home) or starts(coming back after pressing back). [This Picture](http://techblogon.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/lifecycle_of_an_activity.jpg) shows methods you can override to achieve that such as onPause when losing focus etc.

**EDIT**

From the looks of it, it is resetting back to its original state. Post more about how you are setting the location etc. If that is a view you are moving. Then implement a [on drag listener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnDragListener.html) instead of that update. And let me know how that works out.

Comment: I set the location by `v.layout(left, top, right, bottom)` in `MyCustomView.onTouch(View v, MotionEvent motionEvent)`

Comment: And it only happens when you call the update method? Have tried doing instead v.layout, do this.layout.. Also try updating the layout after you update the text maybe.

Comment: Yes, it only happens when `tvDate.setText()`.

Comment: Try getting rid of your invalidate. Because TextView may already be calling that to refresh the views. Also store you new left right positions, and assign it again to the layout before drawing, maybe that will help. So instead of v.layout do this layout, and try doing it again before drawing

Comment: Also return true in your onTouch because you are interested in the other events from this view

Comment: Nothing changed. @Zaid Qureshi

Comment: Someone says, when `View` wrapped into `LinearLayout` or `RelativeLayout`, `View.getLayoutParams() instanceof MarginLayoutParams.class == true`, this `MarginLayoutParams` causing `MyCustomView` back to original location. `MarginLayoutParams.setTopMargin()` solves his or her problem, but it is not work for me.

Comment: If you are interested in his or her solution, check this Chinese website: http://blog.csdn.net/Sasoritattoo/article/details/39473809

Comment: I am not sure how that would effect you. The only problem is that somehow the values are resetting back to the original position. Where do you set the original position?

Comment: try implementing how [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9398861/4667831) implements it

Comment: @Elltz she might be right. When `tvDate.setText()` I do not lay them out but just pass positions. Instead of `v.layout()`, [that answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9398057/android-move-a-view-on-touch-move-action-move/9398861#9398861) you provided could be a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is to <strike>`invalidate` your `CustomView` after you `TextView.setText()`</strike> `setText()` before you layout or pass in values for your left, rigth, ...

```
private void processDrag(View v, MotionEvent event){       
    if(listener != null){
        // calculate index by new position
        listener.update(index);
    }        
    // calculate new position(left, top, right, bottom)
    v.layout(newLeft, newTop, newRight, newBottom); 
}
//i think you should take out invalidate() in your onTouch()
```

Why? `TextView.setText()` triggers `invalidate` & `requestLayout()` at them same time to force a quick layout, but `Invalidate()` just tells its parent that it is dirty, so it needs to do a top down layout pass.

(*im confused so i won't continue to back this up, hence i jump*). Your `TextView` is inside a parent layout who's grand child is your custom view, and `invalidate()`, re-lays all of them hence sends your custom view back to its position, however if you exclude that, and call an explicit `invalidate()` in your Custom view it tells it parent that its dirty and the same process happens, but this time only with the `RelativeLayout`

user: Zaid Qureshi has already made this points known to you.

Also i do not know if you know that the layoutParams being given to your customView is from the parent who you do not control much but the os, and the injected Params are what is uses to layout and give padding etc etc to your View, and since you do not lay them out but just passes positions.

Hope i make sense to you & it helps