# Android: Screen bottom coordinate is beyond visible area

Tags: android, android-screen

I'm trying to create the control, that allows moving view with the finger. To do this, I follow recommendations from **[this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31094315/6144793)**.

But presented method needs some modification, to prevent my view from being moved beyond the screen. I found out how to get `maxY` and `maxY` coordinates - for my Samsung Galaxy A6 it's **1080**x**1920**. But the problem is, that my `maxY` is deep beyond the visible bottom edge of the device.

So my control almost disappears, when reaches **Y** about **1650**. What 300 more pixels go for. I can suppose, that this is `NavigationBar` height + my control view height, but this also doesn't place my control as expected.

I define max coordinates with this method.

```
private void setMaxCoordinates(int viewWidth, int viewHeight) {
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Point displaySize = new Point();
    display.getSize(displaySize);
    maxX = displaySize.x - viewWidth;
    maxY = displaySize.y - viewHeight;
}
```

Please, help me to define the correct formula to detect bottom edge coordinate.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a solution. First of all I was wrong with getting bottom coordinates with the help of `WindowManager`. This just gives you height of your screen in pixels, that is not related to the container. So to detect your bottom coordinate this way, you have to consider:

- `StatusBar` height.
- `NavigationBar` height.
- Height of all views that lokated higher, then your container.
- Height of your own control view (`ImageView` in my case).

So formula will look like this.

```
maxY = windowHeight - (statusBarHeight + navBarheight + allUpperViewsHeight + yourViewHeight)
```

The correct way to define the bootom of your container, is to get the container's height and deduct your control height.

```
maxY = containerHeight - yourViewHeight;
```