# How to move FloatingActionMenu over the screen?

Tags: android, floating-action-menu, floating-action-menu-listener

I'm Using **clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu** library to add Floating Action Buttons. All the functionalities working properly. Now I want to move the FloatingActionMenu In the screen as the User wish. Is there any method or listener to change the position of the FloatingActionMenu?

Comment: Try this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46370836/android-movable-draggable-floating-action-button-fab

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android - Movable/Draggable Floating Action Button (FAB)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46370836/android-movable-draggable-floating-action-button-fab)

Comment: I tried the above answer. It working for Floating Action Button. But not for FloatingActionMenu