# setting image using setX() and setY() but not able to position at the correct place

Tags: java, android, image

Here is the main Java file.
Problem arises when i try to use setX and setY, the image is shifted to left and to bottom and moves relative to touch but not on the touch position.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public ImageView imageView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    imageView = findViewById(R.id.imgv);
    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.pawn);
    imageView.setScaleX((float) 0.1);
    imageView.setScaleY((float) 0.1);
    imageView.setX((float)0);
    imageView.setY((float)0);
}
public void update(float x,float y) {
    imageView.setX(x);
    imageView.setY(y);
}
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {
    float x = e.getX();
    float y = e.getY();
    update(x,y);
    return true;
}
}
```

Comment: If you want to drag view on touch events, follow this
https://stackoverflow.com/a/31094315/7967905

Comment: @SafalSharma i don't want to drag, i want to re-position it on a new touch.
But i cannot do it, it appears at a different position.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that `e.getX()` and  `e.getY()` give you the difference in movement, not the absolute values for X and Y. Add them to the current position:

```
public void update(float x,float y) {
  imageView.setX(imageView.getX()+x);
  imageView.setY(imageView.getY()+y);
}
```