# What should I use to create movable objects on top of an image in Android?

Tags: android, object, maps, layer

I am going to create an android app where I can click on icons and have them layered on top of a picture/layer, and be able to move those around on top of that picture or layer using my finger etc.

I'd like to know if there's anything in android animations that can help me do this or if there's some way of doing this like the html < map >

Answer (score 1):

If you look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9398057/android-move-a-view-on-touch-move-action-move), would be helpful to you.
Using ImageView may solve your issue.