# Dragging view to Left or Right only.

Tags: android, scroll, drag

[image]

I have a `ImageView` which needs to be dragged to LEFT or RIGHT only. I need to acheive the behaviour which is like `ScrollerThumb`.

Then, according to the drag value (x value changes) I need to perform certain operations. I had a look to drag & drop tutorials but it is not functionality I want.

Can you please provide any suggestions on how to achieve that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9398057/android-move-a-view-on-touch-move-action-move

Comment: looks like `SeekBar` is what you need

Comment: @NileshRathod great link. Thanks.

Comment: @Redman thank you. Seems like it was `Seekbar` which I really needed.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried creating a horizontal scroll view and placing the image and other components in it? If you would like to fill left and right of the image you can add transparent View components in any length you want.
Sorry can't help much more without knowing what exactly you are trying to make.