# Saving activity current layout dynamically

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity, save

I'm creating an application with a rather dynamic UI that allows users to add/change the positions of its views and layouts dynamically. If the user decides that current UI design satisfies him he would be able to save all views(`buttons/labels/switches/etc.`) of the activity into a list of "saved" activities. Is there a possible way to do such thing or at least save the positions of all views and layouts?

Comment: Wonderful idea, you can create dynamic layout but for more functionality you have to do R&D. Yes, it is possible to do.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9398057/android-move-a-view-on-touch-move-action-move this might help you

Comment: You can loop over all layout views and store the attributes in a local database for example. Unfortunately this question is too broad for stackoverflow. Try to split the problem into smaller chunks, like "how to loop over all UI elements" and then ask the question with some sample code of what you have tried and what you want to achieve.

Comment: @BasvanStein i though of doing something like this, but I thought there might be an easier way. Thank you for sharing, I will look up now for the looping part.

Answer (score 0):

yes u can , just save the user new position for eash buttons or labels , u can use SQLlite or other ways to save it , then when u display it u get the position from where u save it so it will be the same as what user have change , anyway that is a lot of work ,  i don't advice u to do so . u can do more then one layout and user can choose as themes .