# How should a draggable fragment whose job it is to display content of an object be setup?

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-viewmodel

I have an object **A** which contains a lot of data. It has a counter, a title, a color and a list of other objects. That content is supposed to be displayed in a fragment **F**.

I want to be able to initiate multiple instances of **F** at the same time (my app is designed for tablets, so I have more space then on phones).

**A** is intended to be draggable by the user.

What's the best way for me to structure my code? Should each fragment have it's own ViewModel?

Comment: I think It will go like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9398057/android-move-a-view-on-touch-move-action-move it will make it draggable. Basically, it is working on touch listeners like actions.

Comment: It sounds more like a use-case for a `RecyclerView`. So basically: One fragment. One view model. Several items which are not fragments.

Comment: Since the data is the same, having one view model would suffice.