# Replace BottomAppBar menu with new menu inside a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, menu

I am using a bottom app bar with a Navigation Drawer. When I click on one item of the drawer, a new fragment is added on top of my Main activity. Inside this fragment I want to have a RecyclerView. When the fragment is attached, I want to see the normal menu that I am inflating on the MainActivity, but when an item is clicked on the recycler view I want to replace the menu with a custom one. Right now It´s just adding more items to be existing menu. How I can replace with a new menu, and make the Fab Button disappear or move to the right?

[image]

The button is just to simulate the click on my future RecyclerCiew.

```
public class CourseFragment extends Fragment {
private Menu mMenu;
private MenuInflater mInflater;


public CourseFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_course, container, false);
    Button btn=view.findViewById(R.id.button);



    btn.setOnClickListener(v->{
        mInflater.inflate(R.menu.bottomappbar_edit_remove_menu,mMenu);mMenu.
    });
    return view;

}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    mMenu=menu;
    mInflater=inflater;
    //inflater.inflate(R.menu.bottomappbar_main_menu,menu);
    //super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu,inflater);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your RecyclerView you need to implement a OnClickListener that notify your 
fragment with the desired menu, and then you call **invalidateOptionsMenu()** to 
make **onCreateOptionsMenu()** run again and build the new menu.

Using your example with the button your code would look like this

```
private int menuId = R.menu.bottomappbar_main_menu; // Your initial menu
```

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_course, container, false);
    Button btn = view.findViewById(R.id.button);

    btn.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        this.menuId = R.menu.bottomappbar_another_menu; // another menu that you want to use
        getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu(); // notify that menu needs to be changed
    });
    return view;

}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    // Inflate your menu
    inflater.inflate(this.menuId, menu);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}
```

Don't forget that you will need to create a new menu file with the options you want

Comment: Thanks it worked , but i had to remove the menu inflater on the Main Activity of the fragment. Do you know how i can move right or hide the Fab button when button is pressed?

Comment: See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/31094315/10709983 . You can move your FAB to left/right using onTouch() listener and View.animate() after you press your button